# Consecutive event analysis in R

Tags: r, date, events

I need help with this problem please. I have checked various other posts, but I cannot piece it together. I have data, about 100,000 records of athletes and training events they participated in. I simplified the data, but the approach would suit the entire data set.

Code for the data.frame:

```r
# Fictitious data
days <- seq(as.Date("2016/01/01"), as.Date("2016/01/28"), "days")
events <- c("Run","Swim","Swim","Cycle","Rest","Gym","Swim","Run",
  "Cycle","Run","Swim","Swim","Run","Swim","Cycle","Rest","Gym",
  "Swim","Swim","Swim","Run","Swim","Run","Gym","Rest","Gym",
  "Cycle","Swim")
my.data <- data.frame(athlete = 1, days,events)
# Note - This data repeats for many participants, but I did not include more than 1
```

I need to flag athletes who completed at least 3 swim events per week 
for at least 2 consecutive weeks.

**Edit**: I did not think this through properly. Let's make this a bit more complicated. Let's say we work with running weeks, i.e. a group of 7 days and not calendar weeks, **starting** from the very first **swim** event for each athlete.

**Update**: I have yet another challenge, let's say I want to just look for a pattern of 3 swim events per 5 days for at least 10 consecutive days, **anywhere** in the data.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do a two-step summarization, firstly calculate the number of swims for each week for each athlete and then check if there is any consecutive weeks that have more then three swims for the athlete:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
my.data %>% 
      arrange(days) %>% 
      group_by(athlete, w = week(days)) %>% 
      summarise(n_swim = sum(events == "Swim")) %>% 
      group_by(athlete) %>% 
      summarise(flag = any(diff(w[n_swim >= 3]) == 1))

# A tibble: 1 x 2
#  athlete  flag
#    <dbl> <lgl>
#1       1  TRUE
```

---

*Update*: to set the week starting from the first Swim, use `which.max()` to find out the index where the first `Swim` appears and then subtract all days by this day to get day difference, then if you do modulo(7) calculation, the week number will start from this day:

```
my.data %>% 
        arrange(days) %>% group_by(athlete) %>% 
        mutate(Swim = events == "Swim", 
               w = as.integer(days - days[which.max(Swim)]) %/% 7) %>%
        # the first swim day is set as zero, a modulo of 7 will give week number 
        # starting from this day            

        group_by(w, add = TRUE) %>% 
        summarise(n_swim = sum(Swim)) %>% 
        group_by(athlete) %>% 
        summarise(flag = any(diff(w[n_swim >= 3]) == 1))

# A tibble: 1 x 2
#  athlete  flag
#    <dbl> <lgl>
#1       1  TRUE
```

Comment: I will accept your answer as I have not specified this properly. I'm going to edit the problem and add a twist to it. Maybe you have a solution?

Comment: I don't think your second solution works correctly. Athlete 1's first swim is on 02/01/2016, in the next seven days (inclusive of the first swim), "he" swims 3 times. Also 3 times in the next 7 days thereafter, so it fulfills the criteria of 3 swims in 2 consecutive periods of 7 days. The code returns FALSE.

Comment: It is returning true for me. I assume when you say running weeks, you do not mean weeks overlap, right? It's still one week after another, it's just the start point is different for different athletes?

Comment: You are right, I did not check that the days field is a date. It works, thanks! And yes, it is consecutive weeks, starting fresh for each athlete.

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty code, but check if it works for your dataset:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df %>% 
    mutate(weeknum=week(days)) %>% 
    group_by(athlete,weeknum) %>% 
    filter(events=='Swim') %>% 
    summarise(n=n()) %>% 
    mutate(gt_3=as.numeric(n>=3),
           x=gt_3-lag(gt_3,1),
           flag=x==0) %>% 
    filter(flag==T) %>% 
    select(athlete) %>% 
    distinct()
```